# converting binary data to text in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working with an API that sends the data I need in binary (API doc: https://business.idealo.com/de/assets/api/click-report.html)

Example from the documentation

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=report_detailed_clicks_2017-10-01_2017-10-02.csv.zip
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<binary>
```

I'm only used to APIs that send back data in JSON or CSV format, so I'm not quite sure how to work with binary, is there built-in function in GAS for that?

This is what I have right now

```
let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchOptions);

let response_text = response.getContentText();

let json = JSON.parse(response_text);
```

Comment: Can you provide more detailed information about the API you want to use? Can you provide the URL of the official document of the API you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike yes ofc, just added the link to the description

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `filename=report_detailed_clicks_2017-10-01_2017-10-02.csv.zip` in your question, it seems that the file is a ZIP file. And, when the ZIP file is unzipped, it seems that CSV data is obtained. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
const blob = response.getBlob().setContentType(MimeType.ZIP);
const blobs = Utilities.unzip(blob);
const csvData = blobs.map(b => Utilities.parseCsv(b.getDataAsString()));
// console.log(csvData); // In this case, all blobs are used.
console.log(csvData[0]); // In this case, the 1st blob is used.
```

- In this modification, it supposes that the downloaded data is ZIP data and the file in the ZIP data is CSV data. Please be careful about this.
- If the delimiter of CSV data is not `,`, please give it to the 2nd argument.
- If the downloaded data is CSV data instead of ZIP data, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  const csv = response.getContentText();
  const ar = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  console.log(ar);
  ```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your request of `const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions)` works fine. Please be careful about this.
- This is a simple modification. Please modify this for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [getBlob() of Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getBlob())
- [unzip(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob)
- [parseCsv(csv)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv)

Comment: thank you very much, with one small adjustment it now works:
  const csvData = blobs.map(b => Utilities.parseCsv(b.getDataAsString()));

Comment: @Max S. Thank you for replying. About your reply, I noticed it. So I updated it. I apologize for this. But, I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.